# Customize editext input in android

Tags: android

[image]

How can I customize input type of editext shown in the given figure.Basically my requirement is that edittext should show only the last 3 or 4 digits only initial 12 digit should be in password mode.

Comment: You'll have to do that programatically, I mean, there is no xml config for that kind of situation, have u tried anything?

Comment: Just add a watcher to your editText and change input type programatically when you reached required length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a `TextWatcher` onto the `EditText`:

```
int characterCount = 0;
int asteriskCount = 0;
CharSequence input = null;
input.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        characterCount = count;
        //update input sequence based on changes.
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        //update input sequence based on changes.
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if (asteriskCount != characterCount) {
            //make the visible sequence here.
            CharSequence seq = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < (characterCount <= 12 ? characterCount : 12); i++) {
                seq = seq + "*";
            }
            if (characterCount > 12) {

                for (int i = 12; i < characterCount; i++) {
                    seq = seq + characterCount.charAt(i);
                }
            }
            asteriskCount = characterCount;
            input.setText(seq);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in feature like this. So you have to do it by yourself. You have to make change on the text when the text is changed. To do so .

If you create a custom editText by extending `EditText` then you can overwrite the [onTextChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#onTextChanged%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) method and hanlde the changes.

Or you can use a [TextWatcher](https://www.google.com.bd/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html&ei=iIZtUeXgDcTHrQfK0ICQBA&usg=AFQjCNF5WNMSztKb7uY5NdI7TsXHDjv_QQ&bvm=bv.45175338,d.bmk) to hadle changes.

So when the text is changed set the data except last 3 digitst to *.

But remember that you have to use a String field to store original data in a field.

Comment: This answer should be a comment.

Comment: Thanks Daniel and StinePike for your inputs .. I will try and post my solution

Answer (score -2):

**Below is the code snippet of my TextWatcher:**

```
        private boolean spaceDeleted;
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            characterCount = start;
            //update input sequence based on changes.

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
             // check if a space was deleted
            CharSequence charDeleted = s.subSequence(start, start + count);
            spaceDeleted = " ".equals(charDeleted.toString());

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(s.length()>12){
                return;
                }
            System.out.println("Character Count in afterTextChange->"+characterCount);
            System.out.println("Editable Character->"+s);
            ccNumber.removeTextChangedListener(this);
             // record cursor position as setting the text in the textview
            // places the cursor at the end
            int cursorPosition = ccNumber.getSelectionStart();
            String withSpaces = formatText(s);
            ccNumber.setText(withSpaces);
            // set the cursor at the last position + the spaces added since the
            // space are always added before the cursor
            ccNumber.setSelection(cursorPosition + (withSpaces.length() - s.length()));

            // if a space was deleted also deleted just move the cursor
            // before the space
            if (spaceDeleted) {
                ccNumber.setSelection(ccNumber.getSelectionStart() - 1);
                spaceDeleted = false;
            }

            // enable text watcher
            ccNumber.addTextChangedListener(this);



        }

        private String formatText(CharSequence s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            StringBuilder formatted = new StringBuilder();
            int count = 0;
            /* if(s.length()<12){
                formatted.append("*");
            }else{
                formatted.append(s.charAt(characterCount));
            }*/
            for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i)
            {

                formatted.append("*");

                /*if (Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i)))
                {
                    if (count % 4 == 0 && count > 0)
                        formatted.append(" ");
                    formatted.append(s.charAt(i));
                    ++count;
                }*/
            }
            return formatted.toString();
        }
    });
```

Comment: @shoerat the answers did help me, but that was not the complete answer it showed me the right direction . So thought of putting my ans

Comment: I tried with Phil code, but that was incorrect and havin issue with those code snipptes